# User defined form on windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows c# application, User wants defined some basic field in form template such as TextBox, ComboBox, Checkbox, ... and fill it on run time (almost like SharePoint list but on windows app and very simple). Which application or component or library I can use for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a reference to "System.Windows.Forms". (This should be in your project anyway.) If you already designed any form (e.g. Form1) go and have a look at the file Form1.Designer.cs. There you can see the code that is necessary to create new Controls and add them to a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the fields to your form dynamically as the user presses a button, it's actually not that hard. the big question is what do you do with the form the user designs after that. do you need to keep the form designed by the user, or just the data he enters?